# Why loaded method is ignored?

Tags: delphi

I wonder why, but I can not simply debug my simple program. Loaded method is ignored, it is never executed. No idea why. Look:

```
    TGridObj = class (TComponent)
private
  FPen1:TPen;
  FBrush1:TBrush;
  FChange:TNotifyEvent;

protected
  procedure Loaded; override;


public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property OnChange:TNotifyEvent read FChange write FChange;

  property Pen1:TPen read FPen1 write FPen1;
  property Brush1:TBrush read FBrush1 write FBrush1;
end;
```

.
.
.

```
constructor TGridObj.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
  begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FPen1:=TPen.Create;
  FPen1.OnChange:=FChange;


  FBrush1:=TBrush.Create;
  FBrush1.OnChange:=FChange;
  end;


destructor TGridObj.destroy;
  begin
  FPen1.Free;
  FBrush1.Free;
  inherited;
  end;

procedure TGridObj.Loaded();
begin
  inherited Loaded;
  ShowMessage('');   // this is never executed;
  FPen1.OnChange:=FChange;
  FBrush1.OnChange:=FChange;
end;
```

.
.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Grid:=TGridObj.Create(nil);
Grid.OnChange:=ev1.OnChange;
Form1.InsertComponent(Grid);
end;
```

Thanx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Loaded` is only called when the component's properties are streamed from the form file. Since you are creating it at runtime, `Loaded` does not get called. This is by design.

Your code needs some work anyway to allow for the `OnChange` event to be modified at runtime and have that change filter down to the pen and brush. I'd do it like this:

```
TGridObj = class (TComponent)
private
  FPen1: TPen;
  FBrush1: TBrush;
  FChange: TNotifyEvent;
  procedure DoChange(Sender: TObject);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FChange write FChange;
  property Pen1: TPen read FPen1;
  property Brush1: TBrush read FBrush1;
end;

constructor TGridObj.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FPen1 := TPen.Create;
  FPen1.OnChange := DoChange;
  FBrush1 := TBrush.Create;
  FBrush1.OnChange := DoChange;
end;

destructor TGridObj.Destroy;
begin
  FBrush1.Free;
  FPen1.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TGridObj.DoChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FChange) then
    FChange(Sender);
end;
```

Now there's no need for `Loaded` or anything like that. Because you wait until the `OnChange` events of the pen and brush actually fire before accessing `FChange`.

By the way, in your code it's a mistake to add property setters for `Pen1` and `Brush1` that modify the underlying fields. That leads to leaks and all sorts of mess. Also, be warned that exposing the pen and brush as public properties allows clients of `TGridObj` to change the `OnChange` event. And that subverts `TGridObj.OnChange`.

Answer (score 1):

OnLoaded will only be executed if the component is loaded from a form resource (dfm file).

If the component is created at run time in code only, it will not be executed.

Update:

I recommend to design components so that they can be created and configured at run time too - which means I avoid overriding OnLoaded. The advantage is that no package installation / component registration is needed.